# Android PayPal Mobile Express CheckOut Library -- How to load example

Tags: android, paypal

I have no developing experience but am trying to get an idea for how the PayPal MECL works. I downloaded the SDK (and eclipse), and the Paypal MECL SDK has an example folder structured like this:

```
[folder] Assets
[folder] Bin
[folder] Res
[folder] Src
[file] Paypal_MECL.jar
[file].classpath
[file].project
[file] AndroidManifest.xml
[file] default.properties
```

How would I load this in eclipse to see an example?? Can some one point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

as this is online recharge procedure so you have to just download the MECL paypal and .create a sandbox account and there you can get the app id and reciver mail .so just put the app id and reciver mail into it.